# Setting up selenium grid 2 using chef cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to use chef cookbooks to install selenium grid.

I have two recipes
1) hub.rb - that installs the hub
2) node.rb - that registers the node with the hub.

In hub.rb , all i do is download the selenium grid java file and run a command to start the hub.

```
java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar –role hub
```

That starts up the hub in a particular vm (or node)

In node.rb , I need to register the node to the hub created above using the command

```
 java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar –role node  -hub http://ipofhub:port/grid/register
```

Now the issue is how do i dynamically obtain the Ip of the hub to provide in the node recipe.

Can i , in hub.rb, assign node[ipaddress] to a variable say hub_ip  and use it in node.rb?

in hub.rb

```
hub_ip = node[ipaddress]
```

then in node.rb

```
    java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar –role node  -hub http://#{hub_ip}:port/grid/register
```

I am not sure if the above will work as I havent tested it (waiting for vms to test it out) But is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the ideal way to do it. The only syntax item you need to fix is:

```
hub_ip = node[:ipaddress]
```

Or you can do the whole thing like:

```
hub_url = "http://" + node[:ipaddress] + ":port/grid/register"
execute "adding node" do
   command "java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar –role node  -hub #{hub_url}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax was a typo. The thing that i wanted to ask is about the scope of a variable in a recipe. hub_ip is define in hub.rb and i will also be using it from node.rb. Both hub.rb and node.rb are recipes belonging to the same cookbook. Hub.rb would be run once to setup the hub and there after node.rb would be run as many times as required and each time hub_ip variable should be available within node.rb.

Comment: Or can I do something like this in node.rb (I have a sg role)                                                                     hubnodes = search(:node, "role:sg")
    hub_ip = hubnodes.first["ipaddress"]

Comment: If you really want to use the variable in a "global" way between recipes. I would recommend adding it to your attributes file so all recipes have access. http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html There is no need to make it more complicated like your search command

Comment: I was using attributes but if suppose i say ip = node[:ipaddress] in attribute file. Now, I ll run hub.rb which will create the selenium grid server or hub in 1.1.1.1 for example. If i run the node.rb too in the same 1.1.1.1 then it would work but if i want to create a node in 2.2.2.2 then if i use the attribute wont it point to hub = 2.2.2.2  instead of 1.1.1.1 ? basically i want a variable that will store the ip of the hub and then use  it in many nodes by calling only the node.rb recipe.

Comment: `node[:ipaddress]` will use the IP of the server you are running chef-client on. So you can just switch to the host you want. The other option is to create an attribute override file and override the IP to be whatever you need